# Wordpress Add "login/?msg=membershipRequired" to my URL

Tags: wordpress

I have a website (built using wordpress) running in host server.  I am trying to run my site in local machine. I install xampp, copy of my sites files, and export/import my database to local apache server.

However, when I am trying to open http://localhost/inj/public (/inj/public contains all wordpress files and folders), the url changes to "http://localhost/inj/public/login/?msg=membershipRequired" and the page shows "Object not found!".

I have changed my site and home url from wp-options table. But the problem is still there.

Any help?

Comment: wp-membership / buddypress or something installed ?

Comment: Yes, there are several plugins install for the website, including woocommerce, what shall I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using WooCommerce and have a restriction accidentally added? Have found something about it here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-settings/

Comment: Yes, there are several plugins install for the website, including woocommerce, I will read the link and get back to you.

Comment: You can try disabling the plugins first to see if the problem is with them, then you can look further to it

Comment: I am not able to access to wordpess admin page in order to change the woocommerce setting, is there any way if I can change the the setting from woocommernce files? so how can I disabling the plugins whilst I cannot access to wordpess admin page?

Comment: If you go to your File Manager, you can disable plugins there -> wp-content -> plugins just change the folder name, add one letter or number and you will see if the plugins are the case here.

Comment: I have changed plugins folder names but this does not help, gives me Falat Error as follows: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_settings() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sensei-content-drip\includes\class-scd-ext-settings.php:44 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sensei-content-drip\includes\class-scd-ext-utilities.php(136): Scd_Ext_Settings->get_setting('scd_drip_messag...') ............

Comment: looks like your theme has a dependency on it.

Comment: Any solutions to that?